# flutter TextFormField custom validator

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have layout with dynamic TextFormField like this image

how to TextFormField validator check the checkbox first, error message only show if checkbox is checked, but now my code always show error message while checkbox is not checked

this how I add TextFormField and controller

```
value.result.forEach((datas) {

goodSolution.add({
          "id": datas.id,
          "keterangan": datas.keterangan,
          "checked":false
        });

    final controller = TextEditingController();
    final field = TextFormField(
      autovalidateMode:
      AutovalidateMode
          .onUserInteraction,
      controller: controller,
      validator:
      RequiredValidator(
          errorText:
          datas.keterangan+" wajib diisi"),
      keyboardType:
      TextInputType
          .multiline,
      textInputAction:
      TextInputAction
          .newline,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 1,
    );
    _controllers.add(controller);
    _textfields.add(field);
  });
```

and this how to validate

```
void btnAction() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dismissOnTouchOutside: false,
      dismissOnBackKeyPress: false,
      dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
      animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
      title: 'xxx',
      desc: 'xxxx',
      btnOkText: 'Yes',
      btnCancelText: 'No',
      btnOkOnPress: () {
        xxx();
      },
      btnCancelOnPress: () {},
    ).show();
  }
```

and this code when checkbox is changed

```
Checkbox(                                                                
value: goodSolution[index]["checked"],                                                                     
onChanged: (value) {                                              
setState(() {                                                                  
goodSolution[index]["checked"] = true;                                                                       
});                                                                             
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: (value) {
    if (isChecked) {
      return RequiredValidator(
errorText:datas.keterangan+" wajib diisi");
      }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Comment: where is the isChecked from? because I'm using dynamic textformfield and don't know which index is checked

Comment: you do have a checked list for each item ?

Comment: yes, I have updated the question, please check with keyword `this line`

Comment: It would be better if you update proper widget